# Использование posix блокировки чтения-записи во вложенных функциях

Tags: c, многопоточность, unix, pthread

Всем доброго вечера!
Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то зарекомендовавший себя способ решения проблемы :

1. есть функция F, которая захватывает posix-ный примитив синхронизации *rwlock*, перед работой с данными D
2. есть другая функция, которая так же захватывает *rwlock*, работает с данными D,  и в процессе работы с этими данными вызывает функцию F.

Есть ли какой-то способ при таком порядке вызовов работать с *rwlock* и избежать дедлоков и рассинхронизации(в случае, если освобождать *rwlock* перед входом в функцию F)? Я в курсе, что при использовании рекурсивного мьютекса этих проблем бы не было, но мне нужна именно блокировка чтения-записи, а она, насколько мне известно, рекурсивный захват не поддерживает, по крайней мере во FreeBSD.

**UPD.** 
@avp, да, я хочу примитив `pthread_rwlock_t` использовать. блокируя его на чтение, можно будет "гулять" по списку, блокируя на запись - редактировать список. Проблема в том, что в некоторых потоках необходимо:

1. найти некоторые элементы списка и удалить их,
   а в других :
2. функция удаления может быть вызвана отдельно

например, если мы в потоке только с этим элементом списка работали, и он себя исчерпал, то искать нам его не нужно. В первом варианте операцию поиска и удаления логически разделять нельзя, и было бы целесообразно просто перед началом поиска захватить блокировку на запись, удалить, все что попало под условия, и освободить. Но функция удаления вызывается и из других потоков, а значит должна ту же блокировку захватывать. Тут можно сделать то, что предложил VladD, если в функции удаления нет еще какой-нибудь логики, - просто сделать обертку. Но эта доп. логика есть - там еще перед удалением куча проверок производится, которые к данному списку никакого отношения не имеют, их было бы разумнее выполнять не под блокировкой, по возможности разумеется. Возможно я смогу все эти проверки куда-нибудь вынести, например в ту же обертку, тогда вобщем то должно работать.

Но может быть есть еще какие-то способы синхронизации подобных схем, которыми пользоваться удобнее? Так, чтобы много потоков одновременно могли по списку бегать и что-то искать, и только в одном можно было список редактировать, запрещая на это время всем остальным с ним работать.

Comment: @margosh, весь код свой и его можно переделывать?

Comment: нет, это переработка сервера, который пока работал последовательно

Comment: @margosh, значит блокировок в прграмме не было, и можно писать свои?

Я имею в виду, что для решения Вашей проблемы надо просто написать пару функций, скажем, `lock_22(), unlock_22()` (не знаю, как назвать), которые будут безопасно делать вложенную блокировку.

Кстати, у Вас это действительно вложенные (сбалансированные) lock-unlock, или может быть несколько lock (реально нужен первый из них) и только один unlock?

Если в принципе такое решение подходит, то могу попробовать набросать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[[[@margosh](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh), вот после этого описания я вообще особых проблем почему-то не вижу.

Единственное, это то, что получив wrlock, надо проверить, а не удален ли уже элемент другим потоком? И все функции должны работать выполняя эту проверку.

IMHO в любом случае без нее не обойтись, т.к. нельзя "повысить" уровень блокировки с READ до WRITE. Все n rdlock (если в потоке их было несколько) в любом случае надо освобождать перед wrlock.

А возможно тут подойдет такое решение. Конечно, оно работает только в случае, когда потоку для дальнейшей работы не важно, удален ли реально элемент.

Функции (потоки) поиска делают rdlock на список. Найденные элементы (кандидаты на удаление) помещаются в некое множество (в списке они остаются, в множество кладем указатель или какой-нибудь ID элемента). С ним, естественно, связаны мьютекс и семафор, на котором висит поток, который и будет удалять элементы. Именно он и делает wrlock.

Что-то в таком духе.

***UPDATE***

[[[[@margosh](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh), точно не знаю, такой ли код Вы хотели бы видеть, но я решил достаточно формально подойти к вложенным wrlock и вот, надеюсь это Вам пригодится.

Функцию `lock22()` можно вызывать уже имея лок, количество вызовов `unlock22()` должно соответствовать количеству вложенных вызовов `lock22()`. Для выхода со всех уровней вложенности и потери лока вызывайте `force_unlock22()`.

Во все функции передается адрес структуры `struct lock22`, которая содержит **`pthread_rwlock_t lock`**. Структура должна быть инициализирована перед использованием вызовом `init_lock22()`.

**Важно**. Все остальные вызовы `pthread_rwlock_rdlock()` и других аналогичных функций  должны относится ***именно к этому полю*** lock в `struct lock22`.

```
// lock22.c avp 2013 nested pthread_rwlock_wrlock, pthread_rwlock_unlock
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/* 
   #include "lock22.h"
   put next lines to lock22.h 
*/
struct lock22 {
  pthread_t owner;
  int       cnt;
  pthread_rwlock_t lock;
};

extern int 
  init_lock22 (struct lock22 *p, const pthread_rwlockattr_t *a),
  lock22 (struct lock22 *p),
  unlock22 (struct lock22 *p),
  force_unlock22 (struct lock22 *p);
/* end of "lock22.h" */

// returns 0 if OK
int
init_lock22 (struct lock22 *p, const pthread_rwlockattr_t *a)
{
  p->owner = 0;
  p->cnt = 0;
  return pthread_rwlock_init(&p->lock, a);
}

static pthread_mutex_t locki = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// returns 0 if OK
int
lock22 (struct lock22 *p)
{
  int rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&locki);
  if (rc)
    return rc;
  pthread_t self = pthread_self();

  if (!pthread_equal(p->owner, self)) { // try to acquire wrlock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locki);
#if TEST
    printf ("CNT %d owner %p self %p\n",
            p->cnt, (void *)p->owner, (void *)self);
#endif
    if (rc = pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&p->lock))
      return rc;
    // acquired wrlock
    p->cnt = 1;
    p->owner = self;
  } else {  // already has wrlock
    p->cnt++;
    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&locki);
  }
  return rc;
}

// returns 0 if OK
int
unlock22 (struct lock22 *p)
{
  int rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&locki);
  if (rc)
    return rc;
  pthread_t self = pthread_self();

  if (!pthread_equal(p->owner, self)) { 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locki);
    return -1; // logical error. Only owner thread can call unlock22()
  }

  if (--p->cnt == 0) { // last nested lock
    rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&p->lock);
    p->owner = 0;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&locki);
  return rc;
}

// returns 0 if OK
int
force_unlock22 (struct lock22 *p)
{
  int rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&locki);
  if (rc)
    return rc;
  pthread_t self = pthread_self();

  if (!pthread_equal(p->owner, self)) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locki);
    return -1; // logical error. Only owner thread can call unlock22()
  }

  rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&p->lock);
  p->owner = 0;
  p->cnt = 0;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&locki);
  return rc;
}

#if TEST
/*******************************************************
Testing code
*******************************************************/

struct lock22 l22;

void
test (char *msg)
{
  printf ("%s lock22() %d\n", msg, lock22(&l22));
  printf ("%s cnt = %d\n", msg, l22.cnt);
  printf ("%s unlock22() %d\n", msg, unlock22(&l22));
  printf ("%s cnt = %d\n", msg, l22.cnt);
}

void *
ptest (void *a)
{
  puts("Thread go");
  test("ptest1");

  printf ("ptest lock22() %d\n", lock22(&l22));
  printf ("cnt = %d\n", l22.cnt);
  test("ptest2-nested");
  test("ptest3-nested");
  printf ("ptest unlock22() %d\n", unlock22(&l22));
  printf ("cnt = %d\n", l22.cnt);
  puts("Thread exit");
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  pthread_t th;
  void *ptres;

  printf ("init_lock22(): %d\n", init_lock22(&l22, NULL));

  test("main1");
  test("main2");

  printf ("main lock22() %d\n", lock22(&l22));
  printf ("cnt = %d\n", l22.cnt);

  pthread_create(&th, NULL, ptest, NULL);

  puts ("Enter for continue");
  getchar();

  test("main3-nested");
  test("main4-nested");
  printf ("main unlock22() %d\n", unlock22(&l22));
  printf ("main cnt = %d ???\n", l22.cnt);

  pthread_join(th, NULL);

  printf ("fin cnt = %d\n", l22.cnt);
  puts("End");
}
#endif
```

Делал в ubuntu, тщательно не тестировал.

Трансляция в ./a.out

```
gcc lock22.c -pthread -DTEST
```

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

***UPDATE-2***

Сообразил, что для нормального использования в `init_lock22()` надо добавить аргумент - атрибуты лока. Тогда будет четко соответствовать `man pthread_rwlock_init`.

Код выше поправил.

Comment: я пока не готова ответить на вопрос, пройдет ли там подобная схема, кода нет под рукой, но сама идея создавать еще один поток, чтобы удалять элементы из списка мне не очень нравится хотя бы по той причине, что потоков там и так хватает, в отличие от предполагаемого количества ядер, на которых это будет исполняться.
>>нельзя "повысить" уровень блокировки с READ до WRITE
я бы не повышать хотела, а скорее рекурсивно захватить write в фукции, где выполняется проход по списку и удаление.

Comment: Но только вот найдя очередной элемент для удаления, rdlock придется отдавать, а после удаления брать еще раз и вот тут неприятный момент. 

Элемент с которого мы собирались продолжать просмотр списка м.б. кем-то уже удален. И если все детали тщательно не продумать, то для связных списков это фатально.

А если начинать с начала списка, то совсем некрасиво.

Comment: @avp,rdlock - только для функций, в которых удаления не происходит, там, где я собираюсь элемент удалять, повторюсь, мне было бы удобно захватить wrlock еще до начала поиска элементов, подходящих под условие.

Comment: @margosh, написал в UPDATE своего ответа код lock-unlock для вложенных вызовов.

Comment: @avp: о, вы написали рекурсивый `mutex` на базе нерекурсивного :)

Comment: @avp, интересное решение, оно  должно подойти, спасибо большое!

Comment: Сообразил, что для нормального использования в init_lock22() надо добавить аргумент - атрибуты лока. Тогда будет четко соответствовать man pthread_rwlock_init.

Код выше поправил.

@margosh, возможно для некоторого "единообразия" стоит написать обертку над `pthread_rwlock_rdlock` (другими из семейства `pthread_rwlock_...` тоже?) для использования `pthread_rwlock_t lock` из `struct lock22`.

--

Лимит комментариев здесь исчерпал...

Answer (score 2):

Хм. Попробуйте разделить функции на части, одна из которых берёт блокировку, а другая выполняет работу, зная, что блокировка взята.

Освобождать блокировку -- плохая идея: ведь в этот момент другой поток может её взять и изменить состояние объектов, с которыми вы работали до отпускания блокировки.

То есть у вас будет:

```
F:
    take the lock
    call F_realwork
    release the lock

Other:
    take the lock
    do some work
    call F_realwork
    do some more work
    release the lock
```

Кстати, подумайте, с хорошими шансами вам просто *не нужна* версия `F` с блокировкой.

Comment: это в моем случае не подойдет - функция, которая вызывается внутри, может самостоятельно вызываться из других потоков, и блокировка ей нужна. Это можно было бы сделать так : продублировать вложенную функию F,в одной из них блокировку убрать, и из данного потока вызывать копию без блокировки, а из других - копию с блокировкой, но это какое-то некрасивое совсем решение проблемы.

Comment: @margosh: ну хорошо, пускай другие потоки вызывают `F`, а где надо -- `F_realwork`.

Comment: мне не нравится такое решение проблемы, может что-то лучше есть? мне кажется что это вполне распространенная проблема, наверняка в плюсах она решается какими-то другими примитивами.
UPD : пардон, вы имели ввиду обертку, может обертка и пойдет, посмотрю внимательнее. если есть еще идеи - буду рада ознакомиться.

Comment: @margosh: во-первых, рекурсивные блокировки позволяют вообще не думать :) Во-вторых, обычно если одна и та же операция может как требовать внешней блокировки, так и блокировать самостоятельно по обстоятельствам -- значит, что-то не так в моём дизайне.

Comment: @margosh: (1) Я имел в виду C++ и [recursive_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex). (2) Ну, это сложно объяснить, я сам толком не понимаю. В семантически чистом дизайне не должно быть функций, которым нужно и так и так, иногда брать блокировку, иногда нет. Ну давайте пример попроще: если входной параметр функции -- указатель, то она должна или всегда принимать NULL, или всегда отвергать, а если надо иногда такое поведение, а иногда другое, скорее всего надо переписать.

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется этот пример к моей ситуации отношения не имеет, мне не нужно иногда блокировку захватывать, иногда - нет, мне нужно, чтобы можно было безопасно использовать функцию F как самостоятельно, так и в случае, когда она вызывается внутри еще одной функции (пусть будет F0), которая захватывает ту же блокировку и работает с теми же данными. Функция F - по сути, удаляет элемент списка с некоторой доп логикой, функция F0 - с этим списком работает и решает, нужно ли что-то из него удалить.

Comment: @margosh: ну, если у вас такая логика, что иногда удаление уходит наружу, а иногда вызывается изнутри, значит, так пусть и будет. Попробуйте обёртку. Только функцию без обёртки сделайте приватной. (И может быть, в ней будет удобнее другой список аргументов -- например, указатель на следующий элемент в списке, или ещё что-то, по месту будет виднее.)

Comment: @margosh Так чем же Вам это recursive_mutex не подходит? Лишь бы количество локирований совпадало с количеством освобождений...

Comment: во первых, это С - там никаких приватных методов нет. во вторых - именно блокировка чтения-записи мне нужна по той причине, что есть ситуации, и их много, когда потоки будут только пробегать по списку, что-то выискивать, но не будут его модифицировать, это прекрасная возможность улучшить параллелизм в программе путем захвата блокировки только на чтение - все будут по ней бегать одновременно, пока кому-то не понадобится ее редактировать.

Comment: @margosh, Вы собираетесь использовать pthread_rwlock_rdlock/pthread_rwlock_wrlock?

Думаю Вас известно, что при полученном pthread_rwlock_rdlock нельзя вызывать pthread_rwlock_wrlock. Это должно отслеживаться в логике программы.

Comment: @margosh: А, и правда, раз C, вам придётся самостоятельно следить за правильностью вызовов :) В вашем случае для удаления из списка нужна, понятно, только блокировка на запись, так что дополнительных проблем не возникнет.

Comment: @margosh, т.о. (если я правильно понял) проблема вложенности реально существует только для wrlock?